# Can Circumcision cure Premature Ejaculation?

Tags: sex, penis, circumcision

From [metromaleclinic](https://www.metromaleclinic.com/can-circumcision-cure-premature-ejaculation), its says:

> This clearly **puts away** the prospect of considering Circumcision as a cure for Premature Ejaculation.

From [PristyCare](https://www.pristyncare.com/blog/circumcision-make-you-last-longer-pc0441/) , its says completely opposite:

> The removal of foreskin **increases the time of ejaculation**, thus making the male last longer during sexual intercourse.

Can Circumcision cure Premature Ejaculation?

Comment: I find that second link little more than a marketing pitch. It is not, IMO, a credible source. In the few minutes I spent looking at it, I got bombarded with popups wanting me to schedule a procedure with them. The first link at least says they base their conclusions on scientific studies. Although they fail to specify which studies they refer to, I still found it more credible. For a much more credible source, have a look at Table 1 in [this article](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC7985026/). Incidentally, there is a cure for PE, and it doesn't involve surgery or drugs.